# cURL Works, JavaScript XHR Don't - CORS with REST API

Tags: javascript, http, curl, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I've been CORSed to death for days while trying to use a browser to interact with a REST api ([Cisco's CSR1000v REST API](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/restapi/restapi/RESTAPIclient.html#wpxref95738)).  The API's required basic authentication returns a token which is then used to do RESTful things - GETs, DELETEs, etc.

Cygwin64's cURL worked/works fine but I could not get a browser to do it (basic authentication) no matter what I tried. ...and tried, and tried, and tried.  I finally installed a 'CORS Everywhere' Firefox plugin and poof, it worked!

My question is:  If the server resource, NGINX in this case, does not have the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` set, does that make CORS literally impossible from (non hacked/plugin'ed) Web browsers?  I don't have access to the NGINX to configure it, by the way.

I saw the fetch api but it appears that browsers are basically not supporting the `no-cors` mode at this time.

Comment: Unfortunately , browsers are stubborn

Comment: Q: “My question is: If the server resource, NGINX in this case, does not have the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' set, does that make CORS literally impossible from (non hacked/plugin'ed) Web browsers?”  A: Yes. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35553500/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-https-www-website-com/35553666#35553666 for one good summary at SO.